# Vertica: ORDER BY ASC and DESC for date and time is giving same value

Tags: database, vertica

I'm using Vertica db and trying to sort the rows by DESC and ASC in which both gives the same output. The rows value are in date and time like shown below.

```
testdb=> SELECT queue_entry_timestamp, acquisition_timestamp, (acquisition_timestamp-queue_entry_timestamp) AS 'queue wait' FROM V_MONITOR.RESOURCE_ACQUISITIONS WHERE node_name ILIKE '%node0001' AND pool_name = 'test01' ORDER BY 'queue_entry_timestamp' desc limit 5;
     queue_entry_timestamp     |     acquisition_timestamp     |   queue wait
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------
 2023-01-27 03:40:02.259231+00 | 2023-01-27 03:40:02.259239+00 | 00:00:00.000008
 2023-01-27 03:40:02.258851+00 | 2023-01-27 03:40:02.25888+00  | 00:00:00.000029
 2023-01-27 03:40:45.958846+00 | 2023-01-27 03:40:45.958872+00 | 00:00:00.000026
 2023-01-27 03:41:41.958178+00 | 2023-01-27 03:41:41.958185+00 | 00:00:00.000007
 2023-01-27 03:42:42.966845+00 | 2023-01-27 03:42:42.966851+00 | 00:00:00.000006
(5 rows)
```

```
testdb=> SELECT queue_entry_timestamp, acquisition_timestamp, (acquisition_timestamp-queue_entry_timestamp) AS 'queue wait' FROM V_MONITOR.RESOURCE_ACQUISITIONS WHERE node_name ILIKE '%node0001' AND pool_name = 'test01' ORDER BY 'queue_entry_timestamp' asc limit 5;
     queue_entry_timestamp     |     acquisition_timestamp     |   queue wait
-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------
 2023-01-27 03:40:02.259231+00 | 2023-01-27 03:40:02.259239+00 | 00:00:00.000008
 2023-01-27 03:40:02.258851+00 | 2023-01-27 03:40:02.25888+00  | 00:00:00.000029
 2023-01-27 03:40:45.958846+00 | 2023-01-27 03:40:45.958872+00 | 00:00:00.000026
 2023-01-27 03:41:41.958178+00 | 2023-01-27 03:41:41.958185+00 | 00:00:00.000007
 2023-01-27 03:42:42.966845+00 | 2023-01-27 03:42:42.966851+00 | 00:00:00.000006
(5 rows)
```

Could someone let me know how to sort this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is the order by syntax:

```sql
ORDER BY 'queue_entry_timestamp'
```

This actually says to order by a constant string literal `'queue_entry_timestamp'`.  This value will always be the same, for every record in your table.  So your current logic really has no ordering at all.  Use this version:

```sql
ORDER BY queue_entry_timestamp
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks it worked. Can you also help me in getting the last row using the LAST_Value()

Comment: I don't have any context for what the "last" row should be.  You can either comment again, or, better yet, open a new question.

Comment: I want the last row value. I thought of getting it from the last function instead of getting it order by and limit 1.

Comment: If you want the last row as given by some order, you could also use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY queue_entry_timestamp DESC) AS rn`, then subquery and retain the record with `rn = 1`.

Comment: Can we change the time format to be more precise and Human Understandable ?

Comment: Yes, use [TO_CHAR](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Formatting/TO_CHAR.htm).